# How to count how many days passed from the beginning

Tags: mysql, sql

Totally edit my question. Because I guess my first try was too unclear.
I actually have table with three columns. I need to add new column and fill it by  time which passed from begining

```
|| *station_id* || *counter* || *stop* || *time from begining* ||
|| 22500 || 0 || 16:15:00 ||  ||
|| 22710 || 1 || 17:24:00 ||  ||
|| 22790 || 2 || 18:10:00 ||  ||
|| 22670 || 3 || 19:43:00 ||  ||
|| 22800 || 4 || 21:42:00 ||  ||
|| 22920 || 5 || 22:47:00 ||  ||
|| 24050 || 6 || 00:53:00 ||  ||
|| 24010 || 7 || 02:13:00 ||  ||
|| 24280 || 8 || 02:30:00 ||  ||
|| 24270 || 9 || 02:57:00 ||  ||
|| 24250 || 10 || 03:45:00 ||  ||
|| 24249 || 11 || 06:45:00 ||  ||
|| 25270 || 12 || 08:06:00 ||  ||
|| 1190 || 13 || 09:23:00 ||  ||
|| 25230 || 14 || 10:43:00 ||  ||
|| 25201 || 15 || 11:23:00 ||  ||
|| 25215 || 16 || 11:54:00 ||  ||
|| 24605 || 17 || 13:05:00 ||  ||
|| 24577 || 18 || 13:44:00 ||  ||
|| 24580 || 19 || 14:23:00 ||  ||
|| 24583 || 20 || 15:09:00 ||  ||
|| 24585 || 21 || 15:40:00 ||  ||
|| 24610 || 22 || 16:40:00 ||  ||
|| 24850 || 23 || 17:47:00 ||  ||
|| 24840 || 24 || 18:12:00 ||  ||
|| 24500 || 25 || 21:32:00 ||  ||
|| 24760 || 26 || 00:52:00 ||  ||
|| 24100 || 27 || 06:23:00 ||  ||
|| 24791 || 28 || 08:55:00 ||  ||
|| 24938 || 29 || 10:05:00 ||  ||
|| 24943 || 30 || 10:34:00 ||  ||
|| 21602 || 31 || 11:52:00 ||  ||
|| 21609 || 32 || 14:58:00 ||  ||
|| 21800 || 33 || 16:32:00 ||  ||
|| 21630 || 34 || 17:13:00 ||  ||
|| 21646 || 35 || 18:02:00 ||  ||
|| 21640 || 36 || 18:55:00 ||  ||
|| 21650 || 37 || 19:15:00 ||  ||
|| 21670 || 38 || 20:38:00 ||  ||
|| 21654 || 39 || 21:13:00 ||  ||
|| 21680 || 40 || 21:35:00 ||  ||
|| 21658 || 41 || 22:39:00 ||  ||
|| 21600 || 42 || 01:11:00 ||  ||
|| 21760 || 43 || 03:09:00 ||  ||
|| 27580 || 44 || 04:43:00 ||  ||
|| 27453 || 45 || 05:14:00 ||  ||
|| 27570 || 46 || 05:34:00 ||  ||
|| 27560 || 47 || 06:22:00 ||  ||
|| 27438 || 48 || 06:52:00 ||  ||
|| 27550 || 49 || 07:53:00 ||  ||
|| 27530 || 50 || 09:04:00 ||  ||
|| 27200 || 51 || 11:14:00 ||  ||
|| 27240 || 52 || 14:08:00 ||  ||
```

How to update it, and put to last question how many minutes passed from station with counter=0.

My wrong try looks like:

```
select station_id,counter, stop_ends,
IF(TIMEDIFF(stop_ends, @diff := (select (stop_ends) from route ri where ri.train_id=ro.train_id and counter=0)) >= 0, TIMEDIFF(stop_ends, @diff),
SEC_TO_TIME(
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('23:59:59', @diff)) + 1 +
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop_ends, '00:00:00')))
)
as travel
from route ro where train_id = 1130 order by counter
```

It perfectly estimate time, but only within first day.

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  There is no concept of "first" row or "second" row, unless that information is stored somewhere in the table.  Do you have an autoincrementing id?  Or another field that can be used to specify the order?

Comment: Sure I have. I can easily order it in right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not optimize but it's work.

```
set @prefix := TIME_TO_SEC("00:00:00");

select station_id,counter, stop_ends,
if
(
    (@travel := IF(TIMEDIFF(stop_ends, @diff := (select (stop_ends) from route ri where ri.train_id=ro.train_id and counter=0)) >= 0, TIMEDIFF(stop_ends, @diff),
    SEC_TO_TIME(
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('23:59:59', @diff)) + 1 +
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stop_ends, '00:00:00')))
    ))
    <
    (IF(TIMEDIFF(@diff2 := (select (stop_ends) from route ri2 where ri2.train_id=ro.train_id and counter=ro.counter-1), @diff) >= 0, TIMEDIFF(@diff2, @diff),
    SEC_TO_TIME(
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('23:59:59', @diff)) + 1 +
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(@diff2, '00:00:00')))
    )), SEC_TO_TIME(@prefix := @prefix + TIME_TO_SEC('24:00:00') + TIME_TO_SEC(@travel)), SEC_TO_TIME(@prefix + TIME_TO_SEC(@travel))
) as travel
from route ro where train_id = 1130 order by counter
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have one entry per day, and you want to return which day each entry is relative to some other entry.

SQL data isn't really ordered like that. It doesn't generally order your data based on when it's added to the system. Unless you have another column with an incremented id or date added or something, there's not much you can do.

If you do have some kind of incrementing ID column or date added column, you're a simple comparison away from your answer. Show your schema and anyone here can probably help.

If you're still designing this system and you need this functionality, add an extra column. If you're working on an existing system and data set, then you're kind of SOL.